# xml parsing in xcode

Tags: xml, xcode, parsing

I have some problems with parsing XML in XCode.
This is my XML-file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8">
<responses>
    <response name="login" type="call" datatype="string">123qwdaasdt6708uu12edhajsup71y2ehno;aishdp18yu2hbd8y
    </response>
</responses>
```

How to parse and to take string "123qwdaasdt6708...8y"? And how to parse name "login" and show it as string varible?

Answer (score 0):

**The Main point is not**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8">
```

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>`

that make it works better ;)

And to do the thing that you want :

**Output 123qwdaasdt6708...8y and get name="login"**

You should do this following :

```
    public static void debugXML(){

        try {

            Document doc = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder().parse(new File("D:\\Loic_Workspace\\Test2\\res\\test.xml"));

            NodeList ndList = doc.getElementsByTagName("response");

            System.out.println(ndList.item(0).getTextContent());
            System.out.println(ndList.item(0).getAttributes().item(0));




        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SAXException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }



}
```

**System.out.println(ndList.item(0).getTextContent())** ==> gives 123qwdaasdt6708uu12edhajsup71y2ehno;aishdp18yu2hbd8y

**System.out.println(ndList.item(0).getAttributes().item(0));** ==> gives name="login", if you just have login just do *System.out.println(ndList.item(0).getAttributes().item(0).getTextContent());*



Hope it helps ;)